# Find a TD closest to a Parent Div of a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `key` attribute of the `<td>` tag from the below HTML code.

```
<td class="xedit editable editable-click editable-open" id="3" key="details" data-original-title="" title="">Javascript library </td>

<div class="popover fade top in editable-container editable-popup" style="top: 289px; left: 534px; display: block;">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="popover-content">    
 <div>
  <div class="editableform-loading" style="display: none;"></div>
  <form class="form-inline editableform" style="">
    <div class="control-group form-group">
      <div>
        <div class="editable-input" style="position: relative;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">
          <span class="editable-clear-x">
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="editable-buttons">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
            </i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

jQuery used :

```
var x = $(this).closest('div').find('.editable-container').closest('td').attr('key');  //Doesn't work
var x = $(this).closest('td').attr('key');    //Doesn't work
```

Comment: Why are your IDs numeric and not starting with a letter `a-zA-Z` if you're using tables on this page? Also, just add a ID to editable container since it uses multiple classes, not starting with `editable-container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('key');
```